# Shall "One of our goals is make information easier to understand" be added to the Code of Conduct and/or the Website Rules?

Tags: discussion, rules

It seems like the stack exchange site language design and language implementation was created so that people could:

> 1. learn about how programming languages are designed or implemented.
> 2. teach about how programming languages are designed or implemented.

In order to help make teaching and learning less frustrating, it might be help if grandiose site-specific language was discouraged.

As a silly example, a person trying to learn what the English word "**sofa**" means probably does not know what a "**couch**" is. Also, someone learning what a "**couch**" is does not already know what a "**sofa**" is.

The suggestion here is that the website rules encourage people to use words which are as simple and easy to understand as we know how to make it, subject to the constraint that computer language design is a highly technical field.

---

I have noticed that people enjoy inventing new acronyms and initialisms despite the fact that the initialisms are not self-documenting and there are other ways to say things in plain English.

For example, the following is, at least, partially readable:

> "We need shorter, easier-to-read, piece of code which produces the same error message. Please edit your code a bit, so that it is shorter. However, make sure that someone reading  can still tell what the inputs are and it is clear what you expected the code do."

Instead, users of the stack exchange network writing things like this:

> - You must post a **MVCE** (Minimal Verifiable Complete Example)
> - MWE (Minimum Working Examlpe)
> - MRE (Minimum Reproducible Example)
> - MVE (Minimum Verifiable Example)

You and I know the meanings of initialisms or acronyms such as **MVCE**, but knowledge of such things does not exist outside our ***club*** or ***group*** of people.

I was wondering if you are willing to gently steer the language design stack exchange in the direction of making information more accessible instead of making information less accessible.

Users of this website invent new words and teach those words to other users of the same website. The issue that you expecting people to already know what those words mean, without having it previously explained.

hazing people who never written a compiler before is not the same as providing advice to someone on how to write their first compiler.

A practice of excluding people who are not already our friends is not the same as teaching people about the design of programming languages or how to implement programming languages.

Comment: Could you give some examples of the new words invented here? People may not realise what argot has developed around them so it may help to identify the bits you've seen so far.

Comment: A code of conduct is normally binding, and people who violate the code of conduct are penalised for doing so. Rules aren't for encouraging certain behaviour, they're for requiring or forbidding it. Unless you are proposing that people who use acronyms should be punished, I don't see how this belongs in a code of conduct or a set of rules. Hazing novices is already not allowed, and if you see anybody doing that then please flag those comments as "unfriendly/unkind".

Comment: did you actually see someone use MRE here on PLDI? Can you provide more real examples of what you've actually seen people using here? (and link to them please)

Comment: The [Code of Conduct](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) is networkwide and can not be modified per site. Moderators have very, very limited ways of influencing it (move an example, reword a sentence, copy editing).

Answer (score 3):

### Good writing does not need to be in the code of conduct or website rules

I can't speak for others but whenever I use a [TLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-letter_acronym) (tiresome lysergic acronym) I expand it in brakets afterwards and I also try to link to definitions of unusual terms. That sort of thing is just good writing (if only the rest of my writing was as good). I'm not sure that needs to be added to a code of conduct.

Comment: He said "and/or website rules"

Comment: @NikeDattani "Rules", like a code of conduct, imply some kind of enforcement. You can't enforce good writing.

Comment: @kaya3 what is the purpose of your comment?

Comment: @NikeDattani To point out that this answer applies both to a "code of conduct" and to "website rules".

Comment: @kaya3 except that, this was not true at the time that I wrote my comment.

Comment: Indeed I added the missing one in response to this being pointed out but the context has been lost with the deletion of the original comments. I suggest either restoring all the original comments or deleting this whole set.

Comment: @NikeDattani It was true before the edit, for the reason I described. The argument applied equally to both, whether or not the post mentioned both.

Comment: Bruce, I did not delete any comments. @kaya3 based on your last argument, there was no need for an answer (nor the last edit).